# Iterating over different array dimensions

Tags: r

I'm new in R, and I know that, if it is possible, it is best to use built in function instead of for loop and other things like that. So I would like to know if their is a way with function like "apply()" or others, to do the following loop.

```
arr1 <- array(data=rnorm(255,0,1),dim=list(5,5,9))
arr2 <- array(data=apply(arr1,3,function(x)mean(x)),dim=list(9))
var <- array(dim=list(5,5,9))

for(i in 1:9){
    var[,,i] <- arr1[,,i]-arr2[i]
}
```

Thanks

"""""Edit"""" 
I change the code to make it runnable as suggested, and change the "var"

Comment: Something in your example is not right (please also consider making an example that can be run in R - not using "some_data"). In your loop you subtract as single value from a 5x5 matrix and want to write the result in a vector?

Comment: Yes sorry, I'll change that. But yes, you are right, I want to substract one number stored in arr2 to all the number of the 5x5 matrix in arr1 for all the matrices stored in arr1. In fact, the actual code, with the data I use, work fine for me. But I was wondering what was the "right" way as I want to improve my R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution could be:

```
abind:::abind(lapply(1:dim(arr2), function(x) arr1[,,x]-arr2[x]), along = 3)
```